# Take results from JDBC and turn into JsonObject

Tags: java, jdbc, json

I am trying to get the results from my JDBC and turn them into Json objects and I am finding it difficult to do.. This is what I have

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    con=DB.getConnection();
    String query = "Select city,state from zips where zip=10012";
    ps=con.prepareStatement(query);
    String line="";
    while(rs.next())
    {
        line=  rs.getArray("city").toString();
    }
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(line);
```

As you can see I am trying to get the results of the while loop and put them into the String variable and then put that into a JsonObject.

This clearly is not working, anyone have some suggestions? I've been looking around and tweaking this code and nothing works.

If it makes any difference I am using Java 1.8 JDK.
The database connection works and I have tried that query from within MySQL so it is obviously something in the code.

**Update:**
I am getting a blank page when I check to see the output from the query. The reason I want this in Json is because this is supposed to be a restful service for android. The **rs.next()** is being used for a loop to get out all of the results from the query.

Comment: Try to explain what you are trying to do in your `while(rs.next())` loop. BTW you should use `StringBuilder` for that.

Comment: Also "This clearly is not working" is not clear problem statement. Try to [edit] your question and describe you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: Just clarified that now, and Ok I will use stringbuilder and see what I get.

Comment: Actually I may be wrong about StringBuilder. General idea is that if you want to add lots of small parts you get in each iteration then you shouldn't be using `resutl += newContent` but `instanceOfStringBuilder.append(newContent)`. But if you expect your `while(re.next())` to execute only once then your approach should be fine (but you probably should change `whilte` to `if` to make your code clearer).

Comment: Your example seems to indicate an assumption that array.toString produces valid JSON in a string, it does not.  Look into something like `JSONArray city = new JSONArray(rs.getArray("city"));`  Though I'm still not sure this is what you're after.

Comment: Id recommend taking a look at Jackson or GSON. Youll quickly realize that the approach you are trying to take (even if you get it to work) will be unmanageable

Answer (score 0):

Here is a subroutine I wrote, that should solve your problem. At least it works for me, using PostgreSQL. Note that it creates a JSONArray of JSONObjects. So if you would convert it to a String, you will get something like: [{"city":"Berlin","state":"Berlin"},{"city":"Tucson","state":"Arizona"}, ... ].

```
 public JSONArray table2json(ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
  JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray();        
        int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
                Object tempObject=rs.getObject(i);
                obj.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i), tempObject);
            }
            jsArray.put(obj);
        }
        return jsArray;
```